# Слово в кавычки или нет?

Tags: орфография, пунктуация

Знакомство с «нужным» человеком — корректно с кавычками?

Answer (score 1):

Да, в этом случае лучше заключить слово в кавычки. "Нужный" употреблено здесь в переносном значении с ироническим оттенком, поэтому кавычки оправданы. Но в этом выражении они ставятся не всегда. Например, в предложении "В нашем деле он особенно нужный человек"  слово НУЖНЫЙ употреблено в ином значении, без иронического оттенка, поэтому кавычки не ставятся.